# Websocket connection - client attempts to TLS handshake for one address but not the other

Tags: websocket, wireshark

I have a setup which involves devices connecting to a server via web sockets. I'm experiencing a strange problem where they can connect to one test server without issues, but cannot connect to a different server (hosted on Azure).

I've installed Wireshark on both of them, and can watch both the successful connection and the unsuccessful connection. It appears that the unsuccessful one attempts to initiate an SSL handshake.

Here is the successful connection:

[image]

Here is the unsuccessful connection:

[image]

It seems like the client in the successful connection is simply setting up an HTTP web socket, but in the unsuccessful setup it's try to set up a secure connection.
Why would the client be setting up different connections depending upon the server address?

The client code to create the websocket is just javascript, invoking `new Websocket(address)`, and in both cases the address begins with the 'ws' prefix.

---

I have done some further investigation and found another weird behavior. As it happens, there are two domain names pointing to the same server.

If I used the domain name with the top level domain "com" (XXXX.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com), then the connection works.

If I used the domain name with the top level domain "dev" (comutername.mydomainname.dev) then the connection fails, with the weird TLSV1 packet.

Both works fine if I run the same client code on the Microsoft Edge browser.

This appears to be a defect in Chrome's implementation of [The WebScoket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

I have posted a defect here, let's see how it goes. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1067076

Comment: This is off-topic for stack overflow as it lacks code. This is; however, apposite for networkengineering.stackexchange.com, where you should ask instead. Additionally, you'll want to include the actual packet capture files. Pictures of packet captures are as annoying as pictures of code.

Comment: @RossJacobs I think this is a useful question here, because the underlying problem is not in the network.  Developers might ask "my websockets work fine in my local environment but not on the test server, what's going on?". This question might save them the hours that I spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in play here is [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (HSTS)

A browser can be configured so that certain domains have an HSTS policy attached, meaning any insecure link will automatically be converted to a secure link.

This policy will be applied if a request returns a `Strict-Transport-Security` header. But, and here's the significant bit, the Chrome and Firefox browsers *automatically apply* the policy to all `dev` domains.

It appears that up until recently, the Chrome browser and Chrome OS was not observing the policy with regard to WebSocket connections. This has changed, and now WebSockets will observe the HSTS policy.

The upshot is, if you have a websocket using the `ws` protocol and not the `wss` protocol, and it's on a .dev domain, your Chrome and Firefox browser will not be able to connect to it.